# Windows Defender Command line not finding updates

Tags: windows, command-line-interface

I try to update Windows Defender with the command line utility.

```
"C:\Program Files\Windows Defender\MpCmdRun.exe" -SignatureUpdate
```

The result is

```
Signature update started . . .
Signature update finished. No updates needed
```

But Windows Update shows 3 definitions are available and they can be installed with the Windows Update Client.

Any hint on what can I do to update Defender with the command line client?

[image]

Comment: Marc, what ended up being the solution?

Comment: I'm sorry, I don't have a solution yet.

Answer (score 0):

I do it now with a Powershell script.
It's not perfect yet but it works.

```
Set-StrictMode -Version Latest
$ErrorActionPreference = 'Inquire'

$updateSession = New-Object -ComObject 'Microsoft.Update.Session'
$updateSession.ClientApplicationID = 'Defender Updates installer'

$updateSearcher = $updateSession.CreateUpdateSearcher()

'Searching for updates...'

$searchResults = $updateSearcher.Search("IsInstalled=0 and Type='Software' and IsHidden=0")

if ( $searchResults.Updates.Count -eq 0 )
{
    'There are no applicable updates.'
    return
}

$updatesToDownload = New-Object -ComObject 'Microsoft.Update.UpdateColl'

for ( $i=0; $i -le $searchResults.Updates.Count - 1; $i++ )
{
    $update = $searchResults.Updates.Item($i)
    if ( $update.Title -like '*defender*' )
    {
        $update.AcceptEula()
        $updatesToDownload.Add( $update )
    }
}

if ( $updatesToDownload.Count -eq 0 )
{
    'All applicable updates were skipped.'
    return
}

'Downloading updates...'

$downloader = $updateSession.CreateUpdateDownloader() 
$downloader.Updates = $updatesToDownload
$downloader.Download()

$updatesToInstall = New-Object -ComObject 'Microsoft.Update.UpdateColl'

'Successfully downloaded updates:'

for ( $i=0; $i -le $searchResults.Updates.Count - 1; $i++ )
{
    $update = $searchResults.Updates.Item($i)
    if ( $update.IsDownloaded -eq $true )
    {
        $updatesToInstall.Add( $update )
    }
}

if ( $updatesToInstall.Count -eq 0 )
{
    'No updates were successfully downloaded.'
    return
}

'Installing updates...'
$installer = $updateSession.CreateUpdateInstaller()
$installer.Updates = $updatesToInstall
$installationResult = $installer.Install()

# Output results of install
'Installation Result: ' + $installationResult.ResultCode 
'Reboot Required: ' + $installationResult.RebootRequired

'Listing of updates installed and individual installation results:'

for ( $i=0; $i -le $updatesToInstall.Count - 1; $i++ )
{
    '> ' + $updatesToInstall.Item($i).Title + ': ' + $installationResult.GetUpdateResult($i).ResultCode   
}
```